# Is it possible to update a xml file using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is it possible to update a xml file using jQuery? Or do i have to use server side scripting to achieve it?

Thank You

Comment: Presumably the XML file that you want to update lives on the server? If you want to update a client-side XML file, it's a separate can of worms.

Comment: @LarsH the xml files reside on the server,some one has already suggested the only forward is by writing some server side script. I was just looking for any possibility of achieving this using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: ok, the answer is both... you may use js/jQuery to manipulate the XML on the client side, but if you want to update a file on the server, you have to use a server-side program... as @Tim and @dvhh said/implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some kind of server-side scripting (PHP, ASP.NET, ColdFusion, etc.) to edit any files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

yes manipulate your xml as you would manipulate your DOM

```
var jqXML = $(xmlSource);
jqXML.find(yourNodeName).attr(attribute,value);
```

for example

then repost your data to the server